# WordPress coding standards in Emacs

Tags: wordpress, emacs, coding-style

After three years without my beloved Emacs, I managed to make the switch back and am very happy about it. I just lack some little tweaks to make my coding experience perfect.

How can I set up Emacs for the WordPress coding standard setup?

I'm especially looking into getting spaces correctly set [as described here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Space_Usage).

Are there some other interesting configurations to share?